# Registration method option

Tags: security, passwords, registration

I have a registration page based on asp.net membership security. Basically, you finish the  registration and it logs you in.

I want to follow a method used by  quite a few sites where once you have registered you are emailed a link to a webpage where you must login and only then is your registration confirmed. And you know that a valid email was entered by the user.

There are two questions about this:

The URL that you supply in the email must be unique, I assume. and it must be set to expire. Each user must get a different URL, I would think, so you have to mask it or the name of the page where they must validate tier account would be available to everyone. And I think it would have to expire.

how is this accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

I have more experience in PHP, so I'll provide code examples in that, but the concepts should work cross-language.

1. Unique url: This one can easily be based on a hash of the username. (security_salt could be anything, just to prevent others form recreating the url).

   $registerurl = "/resigter.php?id=".md5($username."security_salt");
2. To make it expire after a certain amount of time, make a database with the user's username and the time their page should expire. When the page is requested, the database should be checked.

Comment: Don’t use plain MD5, use HMAC.

Answer (score 0):

Have a table with the following:

```
Username    Email                  Date Registered        Unique ID    Expiry                 Confirmed    Date Confirmed
foo         foo@example.com        2013-12-28 15:30 UTC   123456       2013-12-30 15:30 UTC   true         2013-12-28 15:35 UTC
```

So the link to confirm could be `www.example.com/ConfirmRegistration.aspx?id=123456`. This page will check that the `Expiry` is in the future and that `Confirmed` is `false` to prevent the `Date Confirmed` being updated multiple times and then if these values are OK it would set `Confirmed` to `true`  and set the `Date Confirmed` to the current date.

The ID should be generated using an implementation of the [`RandomNumberGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, so that the IDs are generated in a secure, unpredictable fashion.

Any entries that have `Expiry` in the past with `Confirmed` as `false` can be cleaned up using a scheduled process, allowing the `Username` to be registered again.

Using a unique ID is better than taking a hash of the username because this will prevent someone registering with a real email address, waiting for their DB entry to expire, then registering with a false email address and then using the link in the original email to confirm the false address (as the hash of the username will still be the same). Of course this assumes that the salt is on a global level, but if you're storing the salt per user why not simply link to the random ID instead, since this will have to be cryptographically secure anyway.